# JavaScript display a div when I click an input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, tags

I want to display a block div when I clicked an input field.

```
<input class="indifferent" type="radio" name="decision" value="indifferent"> Indifferent </br>
<div class="input" style="display: none;"> Please help for our company! </br> <input type='text' name='help'> </br> </div>
```

How can I execute it?

Comment: You mean when "Indifferent" is selected? Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28773065/1913729

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple non-jquery dependent solution:

```html
<input class="indifferent" type="radio" name="decision" value="indifferent" onclick="document.getElementById( 'hidden' ).style.display = 'block' "> Indifferent <br>
<div id="hidden" class="input" style="display: none;"> Please help for our company! <br> <input type='text' name='help'> <br> </div>
```

Comment: If you wanted to do same bit of code but inside a function here it is. [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dx8269q9/1/). But, +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".indifferent").click(function(){
    $(".input").toggle();
});
```

Each click on `.indifferent` will change it's display between showing and hiding.

Comment: Would be safer to use `$(".input").toggle( $(this).is(':checked') );` to make sure it reflects the fact that it's checked or not.

Comment: Ah. Very true. I did accidentally ignore this. Good catch

Answer (score 0):

Add the following jQuery.

```
$('input').on('click', function() {
$('.input').css('display', 'block');              
});
```

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/agy7mxhz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to add a class when click insteed of a sigle property (to whatever element) as it will allow you to add now or in the future more style to your div. It's more versatil:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.indifferent').click(function () {
                $('.input').addClass("display")
                 });
        });
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oo7n9xk6/1/)**